# Joystick Sprite Kit as UI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, sprite-kit, joystick

So my problem is that im making a game using Sprite Kit and Ive implemented a joystick that I need in the game and first I wanted to make a speed cap when you drag the joystick and also when I put the joystick as a child to the camera instead of putting it on the map for testing it both wouldn't work. I just started IOS Development a little help would be very appreciated.

Here is my Code for the JoyStick:

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Foundation

```
class Joystick:SKNode{

let base = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "JBase")
let stick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "JStick")
var stickActive:Bool = false
var xJoystickDelta = CGFloat()
var yJoystickDelta = CGFloat()
var v:CGVector = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)

func moveStick(location:CGPoint){
    if (stickActive == true) {

    /*let*/ v = CGVector(dx: location.x - base.position.x, dy: location.y - base.position.y)
    let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)

    let deg = angle * CGFloat( 180 / M_PI)


        let length: CGFloat = base.frame.size.height / 2

        let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * length
        let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * length

        xJoystickDelta = location.x - base.position.x
        yJoystickDelta = location.y - base.position.y


            if (base.frame.contains(location)) {

            stick.position = location

        } else {

            stick.position = CGPoint(x: base.position.x - xDist, y: base.position.y + yDist)

        }
    } // End stick active test

}// End moveStick Function

func endMoveStick(){

    stick.position = base.position

    self.xJoystickDelta = 0
    self.yJoystickDelta = 0

}// End moveStick fun

func getVector() -> CGVector { return self.v}
```

This is what I use to move the player:

The force in the player class:

```
func vectorForce(xDelta:CGFloat, yDelta:CGFloat){

    let xAdd = xSpeed * xDelta
    let yAdd = ySpeed * yDelta
    self.position.x += xAdd
    self.position.y += yAdd

}// End of vectorForce

playerBase.vectorForce(xDelta: joyStick.xJoystickDelta,yDelta: joyStick.yJoystickDelta)
```